# Aseembly ldi instruction

Tags: assembly, avr, cpu-registers

I'm working on a project which consist on migrating an assembly project into C code. I have quite a lot already done but i came across an instruction which i can't fully understand.
It's this one:

```
ldi ZH, high(V_avgbuf)
```

where V_avgbuf is a buffer holding 8 x 24-bit V samples. It was defined like this:

```
V_avgbuf:   .byte   24  ; 8 x 24-bit V samples
```

My question is, after the exevution of the instruction, which is the content of the ZH register? (ZH is a 8 bit register).

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Comment: without the architecture how can anyone understand what the instruction means? There aren't only 1 architecture in the world

Comment: AVR is the architecture.

Comment: you should tag it in your question

Comment: It loads the immediate operand (8 bits) into the ZH register. Is "high" a function or preprocessor thing that selects the highest value of the samples? If so it probably uses that one, if not it probably uses the first value.

Comment: But my question is... does it load the value of V_avgbuf or its address??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because V_avgbuf is bigger in size than ZH, it has to be split into two parts. High takes the 'upper' part of the address.

High is a macro.

See [This](http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/avr_en/beginner/index.html) for reference.

Comment: That was my question..i was wondering if it took the value of that register or just the address.